# How can I bind names from input text to label

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

How can I bind values from shown single text box to label value??
If I use `ng-repeat` in this I'm facing issues to my further functionalities ... Can u please solve this issue? I'm not able to bind between them ... [Working DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZiAJNluHC30BznMemhWn?p=preview)

```js
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $compile) {
  $scope.my = {name: 'untitled'};
  var counter=0;
  $scope.add_Name = function(index) {
    var myName='untitled'+counter;
    var namehtml = '<label ng-click="selectName(\''+myName+'\')">'+myName+' //click<br/></label>';
    var name = $compile(namehtml)($scope);
    angular.element(document.getElementById('add')).append(name);
    ++counter;
  };

  $scope.selectName = function(val) {
    
    $scope.my.name=val;
    $scope.showName = true;
  };
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myapp">

  <head>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <button ng-click="add_Name($index)">Add Names</button>
 <div id="add"></div><br/>

 <form ng-show="showName">
      <label>Name Change(?)</label><br/>
   <input ng-model="my.name">
 </form>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated your code, here's a working version:

```js
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $compile) {
  $scope.my = {name: 'untitled'};
  $scope.mies=[]; // added an array to store the generated values
  var counter=0;
  $scope.add_Name = function(index) {
    $scope.mies[counter]={name: 'untitled'+counter}; // insert a new object into the array
    var namehtml = '<label ng-click="selectName(mies[\''+counter+'\'])">{{mies['+counter+'].name}} //click<br/></label>';
    var name = $compile(namehtml)($scope);
    angular.element(document.getElementById('add')).append(name);
    ++counter;
  };

  $scope.selectName = function(val) {
    
    $scope.my=val; // set my to val instead of my.name
    $scope.showName = true;
  };
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myapp">

  <head>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <button ng-click="add_Name($index)">Add Names</button>
 <div id="add"></div><br/>

 <form ng-show="showName">
      <label>Name Change(?)</label><br/>
   <input ng-model="my.name">
 </form>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: thank you so much.. u done a great job,, u r really rocking,, i'm worrying about this issue from 1month,, finally u done.. tnx alot :D